# How to import fields from a JSON file?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I want to import in my python program only some fields of a JSON file composed of lines of the following type:

```
{  
   "business_id":"Apn5Q_b6Nz61Tq4XzPdf9A",
   "name":"Minhas Micro Brewery",
   "neighborhood":"",
   "address":"1314 44 Avenue NE",
   "city":"Calgary",
   "state":"AB",
   "postal_code":"T2E 6L6",
   "latitude":51.0918130155,
   "longitude":-114.031674872,
   "stars":4.0,
   "review_count":24,
   "is_open":1,
   "attributes":{  
      "BikeParking":"False",
      "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards":"True",
      "BusinessParking":"{'garage': False, 'street': True, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': False}",
      "GoodForKids":"True",
      "HasTV":"True",
      "NoiseLevel":"average",
      "OutdoorSeating":"False",
      "RestaurantsAttire":"casual",
      "RestaurantsDelivery":"False",
      "RestaurantsGoodForGroups":"True",
      "RestaurantsPriceRange2":"2",
      "RestaurantsReservations":"True",
      "RestaurantsTakeOut":"True"
   },
   "categories":"Tours, Breweries, Pizza, Restaurants, Food, Hotels & Travel",
   "hours":{  
      "Monday":"8:30-17:0",
      "Tuesday":"11:0-21:0",
      "Wednesday":"11:0-21:0",
      "Thursday":"11:0-21:0",
      "Friday":"11:0-21:0",
      "Saturday":"11:0-21:0"
   }
}
```

For example I would like to import only the fields: business_id, name and categories.
I tried in different ways, but the program does not recognize the fields and each line is seen as a single field. For example, I have this problem using the following command:

`x = pd.read_json('.../data.json')`

I also tried to import it like this:

```
with open('.../data.json', 'r') as f:
    x = json.load(f)
```

When I try the command

`x = x["business_id","name","categories"]`

it returns the following error

`KeyError: "['business_id' 'name' 'categories'] not in index"`

The program does not recognize the fields in any way.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to import in my python program only some fields of a JSON file composed of lines of the following type:

Not sure if I understood what you mean by 'import' a JSON file, but I assume you wanted to extract a subset of JSON file and save it as a local variable

If so, your code snippet using the default json module wasn't too far off. [`Json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) function returns json data in Python dictionary. Knowing this, we just have to make small adjustment to how you extract the data from the python dictionary

Before we start, I saved your JSON file as 'data.json'

```
import json
with open(r'data.json') as jsonfile:
     data = json.load(jsonfile) # you had it right up to here
     data_import = [data['business_id'],data['name'],data['categories']] #creating local variable
```

Since you're already importing from a JSON/python dictionary, creating a python dictionary as a local imported variable is another good way to keep the data clean

```
import json
with open(r'data.json') as jsonfile:
     data = json.load(jsonfile)
     data_import = {}
     data_import['business_id'] = data['business_id']
     data_import['name'] = data['name']
     data_import['categories'] = data['categories']
```

Comment: Both ways you suggested, give the same error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: That's strange. The second method doesn't even have a list. Have you tried to isolate the problem? Check which line the TypeError is coming from

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake. But it gives error too. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "........", line 36, in <module>
    data = json.load(jsonfile)
  File ".........", line 296, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
MemoryError

Comment: I see that you got a MemoryError, it's likely that it's not a problem with your code, but your JSON file is pretty huge. check here, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399933/memoryerror-when-loading-a-json-file). You might have to break down the jsonfile into smaller subsets

Comment: I copied a hundred lines of lines from the file and saved them to another json file. I tried to load the new file, but it still gives errors.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 32, in <module>
    data = json.load(jsonfile) # you had it right up to here
  File "C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 930)

Comment: I think we have strayed away from the original question too much. I recommend posting another questions regarding your error outputs. It's difficult to read the messages in a comment